# Is there a way to combine partial pattern matching with return?

Tags: haskell

I’m writing a Haskell program that uses [blaze-html](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html) to construct an HTML document. When a `title :: Maybe Text` is not `Nothing`, I want to produce an [`h1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html/docs/Text-Blaze-XHtml5.html#v:h1) from it. I can do it like this:

```
case title of
  Just t  -> H.h1 $ toHtml t
  _       -> return ()
```

Or, in the specific case of `Maybe`, I can do it like this:

```
when (title /= Nothing) $ H.h1 $ toHtml $ fromJust title
```

Can I have (perhaps with a GHC extension) something that looks more like the second example, but for **arbitrary** ADTs? Something like partial pattern matching that just defaults to `return ()`. I imagine syntax like this:

```
-- imaginary syntax
when title of Just t -> H.h1 $ toHtml t
```

Comment: Anything wrong with this ?  `h1 . toHtml  <$>  Just "My Title"`

Comment: @jpmarinier How would it work?  `Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM’`. In any case, it relies on the ADT in question being a `Functor`. Consider instead `data Foo = Baz Text | Baz Int | ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a function of the following type:

```
Applicative f => Maybe a -> (a -> f ()) -> f ()
```

Using [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) you can find several options. So it seems like the most common name for this function is `whenJust`. You can find it [for example in the `relude` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.5.0/docs/Relude-Monad-Maybe.html#v:whenJust).

If you're interested in a generic solution for this problem, the closest thing to achieve is to use prisms from the `lens` library. Below I provide the complete code with a followup explanation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Prism where

import Control.Lens (Prism', makePrisms, preview)

data Foo
    = Bar String
    | Baz Int
    | Quux Bool

makePrisms ''Foo

whenMatched :: Applicative f => Prism' s a -> s -> (a -> f ()) -> f ()
whenMatched prism val f = case preview prism val of
    Nothing -> pure ()
    Just a  -> f a
```

Function `makePrisms` is a Haskell macro which requires to enable `TemplateHaskell` extension. This function will generate prisms with names `_Bar`, `_Baz` and `_Quux`. You can inspect their type in GHCi:

```
λ: :t _Bar
_Bar
  :: (profunctors-5.3:Data.Profunctor.Choice.Choice p,
      Applicative f) =>
     p String (f String) -> p Foo (f Foo)
λ: :t _Baz
_Baz
  :: (profunctors-5.3:Data.Profunctor.Choice.Choice p,
      Applicative f) =>
     p Int (f Int) -> p Foo (f Foo)
```

Types probably look scary but this is because of complicated internals of the `lens` library. I've implemented `whenMatched` function that should help to work with prisms in a simpler way. Here is how you can use it:

```
λ: whenMatched _Bar (Bar "foo") putStrLn 
foo
λ: whenMatched _Bar (Baz 42) putStrLn
```

Comment: `/= Nothing` and `fromJust` is considered a bool blindness and anti-pattern, so you shouldn't this approach. Regarding your question: are you looking for some generic way to match only on the specific single constructor with `pure ()` on all other constructors?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m looking for. I realize this may be impossible, but I just recently discovered e.g. `ViewPatterns`, so who knows what else is lurking there in GHC extensions.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Ah, in that case, I have bad news for you :( Unfortunately, no GHC extension allows achieving the desired behaviour. What you want is something like _first class patterns_ and Haskell/GHC doesn't have that. The closest thing to what you want is using prisms from the `lens` library. But they are not automatically provided. You need to (1) depend on a library, (2) generate prisms using Haskell macros system and (3) use functions to extract required parts of your data types.

Comment: You don't need to go to an external library for this - it's `Data.Foldable.for_` in base.

Comment: @Carl You do need to go to an external library because you can't implement `instance Foldable` for a data type like `Foo` from my answer.